# Redirect gatsby cloud custom domain to another custom domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, gatsby, gatsby-cloud

My website is build with Gatsby, hosted on Gatsby Cloud. I have redirected my gatsby build `example.gatsbyjs.io` to my domain `example.net`, no problem.

Now, I have another domain: `example.com` and would like it to also redirect to `example.net`. (at the moment i have 2 identical websites with just different domain extensions)

I have tried using the createRedirect action in my gatsby-node.js but it doesn't work after rebuilding and deploying

```
createRedirect({
    fromPath: "example.net/*",
    toPath: "example.com/",
    isPermanent: true,
  });
```

From my understanding createRedirect will only work within the same domain / subdomain and here I'm trying to redirect one domain to another.

I've tried using gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect and gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud (even if its automatically added when using gatsby cloud) to no avail.

How could i redirect one domain to another domain with gatsby cloud ?
Or can i somehow make a redirect in the registrar?